# Track Decorator in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

In the below code the greeting value is displayed in the component either 1 or 2 statement is used. then why we are using track decorator?

```
export default class HelloWorld extends LightningElement {
@track greeting = 'lwc World'; ---- 1
greeting = 'lwc World';        -----2
changeHandler(event)
{
    this.greeting = event.target.value;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_decorators), the second paragraph explains when `@track` is needed. So it is not needed for your example. You may find it used unnecessarily in older code, as AFAIK in early versions of LWC it was required for simple properties too.

> @track
> Fields are reactive. If a field’s value changes, and the field
> is used in a template or in a getter of a property that’s used in a
> template, the component rerenders and displays the new value.
> There is
> one use case for @track. When a field contains an object or an array,
> there’s a limit to the depth of changes that are tracked. To tell the
> framework to observe changes to the properties of an object or to the
> elements of an array, decorate the field with @track.

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith...

Comment: I can confirm that @track was required before Spring '20 and getting used to not needing it any more is quite hard!

Answer (score 1):

This community won't know your original intentions with the `@track` decorator it's [no longer required](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_track.htm&type=5&release=224) so you can remove the annotation altogether at statement 1. You can also remove the line below it (statement 2) as it's redundant to statement 1.